# Calculate minimum Traveled distance from L Latlng in T time

Tags: google-maps-api, android, ios, geofencing

I want some functionality in my Android/iOS application i.e. **U** user is travelling to **L** location, So when the **U** is 15 minute away from the **L** location he/she will get some Notification.

**What i tried so far:**

1. Calling google API and get travel time from the current location to the **L** location on a particular time interval, when i found it to very close from the 15 minute, i triggered notification to the user(**U**) and stop calling the API.
2. Geo-fence **L** location in such a way that travel time from enter the fence to the **L** location, should be very close to 15 minutes. When user(**U**) enter into the Geo-fence i triggered notification to the user(**U**) and remove the Geo-fence.

But for 1st methods Calling google API is not the right way to achieve that.
In second method the problem is *My locations are not fixed they may vary*. **So the radius of Geo-fence should be different for every location because travel time is different for the location.**

According to to me Geo-fence is a good solution but its dynamic radius are creating the problem.

So is there any other way to achieve that? Or we can fix the dynamic radius issue of Geo-fence in any way?

Comment: Your question would be a lot clearer if you avoided using X and Y for non-spatial variables. There's nothing wrong with user U or location L.

Comment: ok @Vince, i will update